# Как подключить dll(c++) к с#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Знаю, что популярная проблема. Но нужно срочно, а я вообще не бум-бум.

Нужно подключить вот эту функцию:

```
DLL_EXPORT int __stdcall EvalCRC(IStream* Data, IStream* Params, IStream* Output)
{
    if (!Data) return ERROR_NULL_DATA;

    // Data - это входной поток с прошивкой, контрольку в которой нужно пересчитать
    // Params и Output пока не используются и зарезервированы на будущее
    int Result = PLUGIN_SUCCESS; // По-умолчанию возвращаем результат успешного выполнения

    ULARGE_INTEGER size_;
    LARGE_INTEGER larg_;

    //ENCODE_START

    larg_.QuadPart = 0;
    Data->Seek(larg_, STREAM_SEEK_END, &size_);

    // Считаем КС прошивки
    if (size_.QuadPart == VALIDFWSIZE1 || size_.QuadPart == VALIDFWSIZE2)
    {
        try
        {
            char arr[IDLEN+1];
            ULONG ulong;
            unsigned int caloffset;

            switch(size_.QuadPart)
            {
                case VALIDFWSIZE1:
                {
                    // Калибровки
                    larg_.QuadPart = CAL_POS1;
                    Data->Seek(larg_ ,STREAM_SEEK_SET, &size_);
                    Data->Read(&arr, sizeof(arr), &ulong); // Вычитываем идентификатор
                    arr[IDLEN]=0x00;

                    if (CheckNumber(arr)) caloffset=CAL_POS1;
                    else return ERROR_SIGNATURE;
                }
                break;
                case VALIDFWSIZE2:
                {
                    // Фулл
                    larg_.QuadPart = CAL_POS2;
                    Data->Seek(larg_ ,STREAM_SEEK_SET, &size_);
                    Data->Read(&arr, sizeof(arr), &ulong); // Вычитываем идентификатор
                    arr[IDLEN]=0x00;

                    if (CheckNumber(arr)) caloffset=CAL_POS2;
                    else
                    {
                        larg_.QuadPart = CAL_POS3;
                        Data->Seek(larg_ ,STREAM_SEEK_SET, &size_);
                        Data->Read(&arr, sizeof(arr), &ulong); // Вычитываем идентификатор
                        arr[IDLEN]=0x00;

                        if (CheckNumber(arr)) caloffset=CAL_POS3;
                        else return ERROR_SIGNATURE;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            larg_.QuadPart = caloffset;
            Data->Seek(larg_ ,STREAM_SEEK_SET, &size_);
            WORD wval=0;
            for(unsigned int i=0;i<(cRangeSize/2)-1;i++)
            {
                WORD wword;
                Data->Read(&wword, sizeof(WORD), &ulong);
                wword = (wword >> 8) | (wword << 8); // Переворачиваем
                if (i!=cCSPos/2) wval += wword; // Считаем все, кроме контрольных сумм
            }

            wval=0-wval;
            larg_.QuadPart = caloffset+cCSPos;
            Data->Seek(larg_ ,STREAM_SEEK_SET, &size_);
            wval = (wval >> 8) | (wval << 8); // Переворачиваем
            Data->Write(&wval, sizeof(WORD), &ulong);
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            Result = ERROR_EXCEPTION;
        }
    }
    else Result = ERROR_INVALID_SIZE;

    return Result;
}
```

Пробовал по всякому, то типы данных не совпадают, то просто какие-то вылеты без ошибок и результатов. 
Если это не сложно, подскажите, как должна выглядеть строка подключения?

Comment: Как подключить: [DllImport](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern) - это легко. Как правильно определить типы данных: [Marshalling](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke) - это сложнее.

Comment: А обязательно потоки должны быть в качестве параметров? Может лучше буфер отправлять?

Comment: @Buka Я не смогу переписать под массивы.

Comment: Александр Ли, хорошо бы уточнить, что Вы отправляете. Как на C# выглядит "Data - это входной поток с прошивкой" ? Хотя можно догадаться(предположить), что Data нужно привести к IntPtr и определить функцию нужно так : int EvalCRC(IntPtr Data, IntPtr  Params, IntPtr  Output)

Comment: @JaponDemon, Попробую и отпишусь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подключить то, допустим,  можно так (предполагая, что используется интерфейс IStream из COM Structured Storage):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

[DllImport("mylib.Dll")]
static extern int EvalCRC(
    IStream data, 
    IStream parms, 
    IStream output
);
```

Только обычные потоки System.IO.Stream не реализуют COM-интерфейс IStream, чтобы с ними работать придется реализовать какую-то свою обертку. Можно [позаимствовать из исходников .NET](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,d4850b457dacb414)

Comment: `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)` - ошибка. Функция же ожидает `IStream *`, а не `IUnknown *`! Правильнее писать `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, MarshalAs тут похоже вообще не нужен